# Linux SGX enclave with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, sgx

I saw on the Intel website [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx-sdk/download) that there is an OpenSSL library available for SGX but only on Windows.

Does anyone know if there is also such an extension for Linux SGX SDK?

Comment: According to [Intel® Software Guard Extensions (Intel® SGX) SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx-sdk), Ubuntu 14.04 is supported. Maybe you could try visiting the site from a Ubuntu 14 machine. Or, use an extension to change your browser's user agent string.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work. Same content rendered.

Comment: As of 24/Jan/2017 it seems that there is no OpenSSL for Linux. Ref: https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1896160#comment-1896160

Comment: Later: _(from SGX wikipedia):_ Both in the 11th and 12th generations of Intel Core processors, SGX is listed as "Deprecated" and thereby not supported anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to OpenSSL namely `mbedtls` [here](https://github.com/bl4ck5un/mbedtls-SGX).
It is available for Linux and Windows and the compiled libraries only need to be linked against the application and enclave.

Comment: Does this provide BIGNUM capabilities?

Comment: Yes it does, and there is also a good example provided for client-sever app with an enclave

Answer (score 4):

Linux SGX SSL Crypto Lib has now been open sourced and it's available here: https://github.com/01org/intel-sgx-ssl

Answer (score -1):

[TaLoS](https://github.com/lsds/TaLoS/) is a TLS library that allows existing applications (with an OpenSSL/LibreSSL interface) to securely terminate their TLS connection inside an Intel SGX enclave. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/lsds/TaLoS/).

There also is a [technical report](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/research/technicalreports/2017/DTRS17-5.pdf) containing details about the architecture and performance results.